# vector notation sum three variables

Tags: matrices, notation

I need to express the following summation in some nice form:
$$ pm=\sum_{i=1}^{k}r_i*p_i*c_i$$ 
From a.o. this site I've learned that I can use the elementwise operator $\odot$ like so:
$$ pm=\boldsymbol{r} \odot \boldsymbol{p} \odot \boldsymbol{c}$$
But is there any better looking way?

Comment: Consider the diagonal matrix $C$ containing the $c_i$ as diagonal elements.  Then calculate $r^tCp$.

Comment: Guess that is the easiest option albeit I've to define $C$, but then again the elementwise symbol does look really bad if you ask me.

Comment: How should $\odot$ as an operator of two vectors be defined?

Comment: Is there a relation between $p$ and $p_i$?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I'm not sure if this answers your question but say $k = 2$ then $\boldsymbol{r} \odot \boldsymbol{p} = r_1*p_1 + r_2*p_2$

Comment: @J.-E.Pin $\boldsymbol{p}$ is a kx1 column vector holding values $p_1 , ... , p_k$. pm is unrelated to vector $\boldsymbol{p}$

Comment: So $r\odot p$ is a number, then what is $(r\odot p)\odot c$?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I see what I did wrong here, $r\odot p$ becomes a scalar such that the two equations are not equal... I'll go with your initial suggestion and define $P=diag(\boldsymbol{p})$, such that I get $pm=\boldsymbol{r}^T\boldsymbol{Pc}$. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the diagonal matrix $C$ containing the $c_i$ as diagonal elements. Calculate $r^tCp$.